# How to distinguish first person "futur" from "conditionnel" tenses in speech?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

I am a beginner French student and was wondering: when listening to someone how to distinguish the "futur" from the "conditioneel" tense? They sound the exact same but spelled differently.

for example: j'aurais vs. j'aurai or j'irais vs. j'irai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the large majority of cases, how the sentence is built is enough to figure out the tense used.

There are few cases like the following one where more context is required:

> *Je le saurai* : I will know it.

e.g. : *(Quand il viendra,) je le saurai*

or

> *Je le saurais* : I would know about it.

e.g. : *(S'il était venu,) je le saurais*

Answer (score 1):

Le 25 mai, je souhaiterai l'anniversaire de ma mère.
= c'est une action planifiée dans l'avenir
= futur simple = terminaison **ai** (action in the future)

Le 25 mai je souhaiterais que l'anniversaire de ma mère soit une grande fête. 
= c'est un souhait = Conditionnel = terminaison **ais.** (it's a wish/I hope)

A trick you could use , 
On peut aussi remplacer la première personne du singulier (je) par une autre personne ; On entend alors la différence.
= futur =  le 25 mai je souhaiterai = nous souhaiterons. (you use nous and say it out loud)
= présent du conditionnel =  je souhaiterais = nous souhaiterions